# How to run a javascript file with browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to run a javascript sample project in a browser. I took the code from https://github.com/stevenmiller888/mind and I'm trying to open index.js. I tried to do what they have mention in README file but I could not open it from duo. Please help me with this. I'm new to this.

//These were the steps given
$ npm install node-mind

You can use Mind in the browser by requiring it with Duo or Browserify. Or you can simply use the prebuilt root index.js file directly, which will expose Mind on the window object.

I installed node-moind and duo as well

//index.js -> This is the code I need to run

```
!function(e){if("object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module)module.exports=e();else if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd)define([],e);else{var f;"undefined"!=typeof window?f=window:"undefined"!=typeof global?f=global:"undefined"!=typeof self&&(f=self),f.Mind=e()}}(function(){var define,module,exports;return (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){

/**
 * Dependencies.
 */

var sigmoidPrime = require('sigmoid-prime');
var Emitter = require('emitter-component');
var htanPrime = require('htan-prime');
var Matrix = require('node-matrix');
var sigmoid = require('sigmoid');
var sample = require('samples');
var htan = require('htan');

/**
 * References.
 */

var scalar = Matrix.multiplyScalar;
var dot = Matrix.multiplyElements;
var multiply = Matrix.multiply;
var subtract = Matrix.subtract;
var add = Matrix.add;

/**
 * Export `Mind`.
 */

module.exports = Mind;

/**
 * Initialize a new `Mind`.
 *
 * @param {Object} opts
 * @return {Object} this
 * @api public
 */

function Mind(opts) {
  if (!(this instanceof Mind)) return new Mind(opts);
  opts = opts || {};

  opts.activator === 'sigmoid'
    ? (this.activate = sigmoid, this.activatePrime = sigmoidPrime)
    : (this.activate = htan, this.activatePrime = htanPrime);

  // hyperparameters
  this.learningRate = opts.learningRate || 0.7;
  this.iterations = opts.iterations || 10000;
  this.hiddenLayers = opts.hiddenLayers || 1;
  this.hiddenUnits = opts.hiddenUnits || 3;
}

/**
 * Mixin.
 */

Emitter(Mind.prototype);

/**
 * Learn.
 *
 *  1. Normalize examples
 *  2. Setup weights
 *  3. Forward propagate to generate a prediction
 *  4. Back propagate to adjust weights
 *  5. Repeat (3) and (4) `this.iterations` times
 *
 *  These five steps enable our network to learn the relationship
 *  between inputs and outputs.
 *
 * @param {Array} examples
 * @return {Object} this
 * @api public
 */

Mind.prototype.learn = function(examples) {
  examples = normalize(examples);

  this.setup(examples);

  for (var i = 0; i < this.iterations; i++) {
    var results = this.forward(examples);
    var errors = this.back(examples, results);

    this.emit('data', i, errors, results);
  }

  return this;
};

/**
 * Setup the weights.
 *
 * @param {Object} examples
 * @api private
 */

Mind.prototype.setup = function(examples) {
  this.weights = [];

  // input > hidden
  this.weights.push(
    Matrix({
      rows: examples.input[0].length,
      columns: this.hiddenUnits,
      values: sample
    })
  );

  // hidden > hidden
  for (var i = 1; i < this.hiddenLayers; i++) {
    this.weights.push(
      Matrix({
        rows: this.hiddenUnits,
        columns: this.hiddenUnits,
        values: sample
      })
    );
  }

  // hidden > output
  this.weights.push(
    Matrix({
      rows: this.hiddenUnits,
      columns: examples.output[0].length,
      values: sample
    })
  );
};

/**
 * Forward propagate.
 *
 * @param {Object} examples
 * @return {Array} results
 * @api private
 */

Mind.prototype.forward = function(examples) {
  var activate = this.activate;
  var weights = this.weights;
  var results = [];

  // sum the weight and input
  function sum(w, i) {
    var res = {};

    res.sum = multiply(w, i);
    res.result = res.sum.transform(activate);

    return res;
  };

  // input > hidden
  results.push(
    sum(weights[0], examples.input)
  );

  // hidden > hidden
  for (var i = 1; i < this.hiddenLayers; i++) {
    results.push(
      sum(weights[i], results[i - 1].result)
    );
  }

  // hidden > output
  results.push(
    sum(weights[weights.length - 1], results[results.length - 1].result)
  );

  return results;
};

/**
 * Back propagate.
 *
 * @param {Object} outputMatrix
 * @api private
 */

Mind.prototype.back = function(examples, results) {
  var activatePrime = this.activatePrime;
  var hiddenLayers = this.hiddenLayers;
  var learningRate = this.learningRate;
  var weights = this.weights;

  // output > hidden
  var error = subtract(examples.output, results[results.length - 1].result);
  var delta = dot(results[results.length - 1].sum.transform(activatePrime), error);
  var changes = scalar(multiply(delta, results[0].result.transpose()), learningRate);
  weights[weights.length - 1] = add(weights[weights.length - 1], changes);

  // hidden > hidden
  for (var i = 1; i < hiddenLayers; i++) {
    delta = dot(multiply(weights[weights.length - i].transpose(), delta), results[results.length - (i + 1)].sum.transform(activatePrime));
    changes = scalar(multiply(delta, results[results.length - (i + 1)].result.transpose()), learningRate);
    weights[weights.length - (i + 1)] = add(weights[weights.length - (i + 1)], changes);
  }

  // hidden > input
  delta = dot(multiply(weights[1].transpose(), delta), results[0].sum.transform(activatePrime));
  changes = scalar(multiply(delta, examples.input.transpose()), learningRate);
  weights[0] = add(weights[0], changes);

  return error;
};

/**
 * Predict.
 *
 * @param {Array} input
 * @api public
 */

Mind.prototype.predict = function(input) {
  var results = this.forward({ input: Matrix([input]) });

  return results[results.length - 1].result[0];
};

/**
 * Upload weights.
 *
 * @param {Object} weights
 * @return {Object} this
 * @api public
 */

Mind.prototype.upload = function(weights) {
  this.weights = weights;

  return this;
};

/**
 * Download weights.
 *
 * @return {Object} weights
 * @api public
 */

Mind.prototype.download = function() {
  return this.weights;
};

/**
 * Normalize the data.
 *
 * @param {Array} data
 * @return {Object} ret
 */

function normalize(data) {
  var ret = { input: [], output: [] };

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var datum = data[i];

    ret.output.push(datum.output);
    ret.input.push(datum.input);
  }

  ret.output = Matrix(ret.output);
  ret.input = Matrix(ret.input);

  return ret;
}

},{"emitter-component":2,"htan":4,"htan-prime":3,"node-matrix":5,"samples":6,"sigmoid":8,"sigmoid-prime":7}],2:[function(require,module,exports){

/**
 * Expose `Emitter`.
 */

module.exports = Emitter;

/**
 * Initialize a new `Emitter`.
 *
 * @api public
 */

function Emitter(obj) {
  if (obj) return mixin(obj);
};

/**
 * Mixin the emitter properties.
 *
 * @param {Object} obj
 * @return {Object}
 * @api private
 */

function mixin(obj) {
  for (var key in Emitter.prototype) {
    obj[key] = Emitter.prototype[key];
  }
  return obj;
}

/**
 * Listen on the given `event` with `fn`.
 *
 * @param {String} event
 * @param {Function} fn
 * @return {Emitter}
 * @api public
 */

Emitter.prototype.on =
Emitter.prototype.addEventListener = function(event, fn){
  this._callbacks = this._callbacks || {};
  (this._callbacks[event] = this._callbacks[event] || [])
    .push(fn);
  return this;
};

/**
 * Adds an `event` listener that will be invoked a single
 * time then automatically removed.
 *
 * @param {String} event
 * @param {Function} fn
 * @return {Emitter}
 * @api public
 */

Emitter.prototype.once = function(event, fn){
  var self = this;
  this._callbacks = this._callbacks || {};

  function on() {
    self.off(event, on);
    fn.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  on.fn = fn;
  this.on(event, on);
  return this;
};

/**
 * Remove the given callback for `event` or all
 * registered callbacks.
 *
 * @param {String} event
 * @param {Function} fn
 * @return {Emitter}
 * @api public
 */

Emitter.prototype.off =
Emitter.prototype.removeListener =
Emitter.prototype.removeAllListeners =
Emitter.prototype.removeEventListener = function(event, fn){
  this._callbacks = this._callbacks || {};

  // all
  if (0 == arguments.length) {
    this._callbacks = {};
    return this;
  }

  // specific event
  var callbacks = this._callbacks[event];
  if (!callbacks) return this;

  // remove all handlers
  if (1 == arguments.length) {
    delete this._callbacks[event];
    return this;
  }

  // remove specific handler
  var cb;
  for (var i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
    cb = callbacks[i];
    if (cb === fn || cb.fn === fn) {
      callbacks.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
  return this;
};

/**
 * Emit `event` with the given args.
 *
 * @param {String} event
 * @param {Mixed} ...
 * @return {Emitter}
 */

Emitter.prototype.emit = function(event){
  this._callbacks = this._callbacks || {};
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1)
    , callbacks = this._callbacks[event];

  if (callbacks) {
    callbacks = callbacks.slice(0);
    for (var i = 0, len = callbacks.length; i < len; ++i) {
      callbacks[i].apply(this, args);
    }
  }

  return this;
};

/**
 * Return array of callbacks for `event`.
 *
 * @param {String} event
 * @return {Array}
 * @api public
 */

Emitter.prototype.listeners = function(event){
  this._callbacks = this._callbacks || {};
  return this._callbacks[event] || [];
};

/**
 * Check if this emitter has `event` handlers.
 *
 * @param {String} event
 * @return {Boolean}
 * @api public
 */

Emitter.prototype.hasListeners = function(event){
  return !! this.listeners(event).length;
};

},{}],3:[function(require,module,exports){

/**
 * Expose `htanPrime`.
 */

module.exports = htanPrime;

/**
 * Derivative of the hyperbolic tangent function.
 *
 * @param {Number} z
 */

function htanPrime(z) {
  return 1 - Math.pow((Math.exp(2 * z) - 1) / (Math.exp(2 * z) + 1), 2);
}

},{}],4:[function(require,module,exports){

/**
 * Expose `htan`.
 */

module.exports = htan;

/**
 * Hyperbolic tangent function.
 *
 * - Useful for inputs between -1 and 1
 */

function htan(z) {
  return (Math.exp(2 * z) - 1) / (Math.exp(2 * z) + 1);
}
},{}],5:[function(require,module,exports){

/**
 * Expose `Matrix`.
 */

module.exports = Matrix;

/**
 * Matrix.
 *
 * @param {Object|Array} opts
 * @return {Object} this
 */

function Matrix(opts) {
  if (!(this instanceof Matrix)) return new Matrix(opts);

  if (Array.isArray(opts)) { // Passing in values
    this.numRows = opts.length;
    this.numCols = opts[0].length;

    for (var i = 0; i < this.numRows; i++) {
      this[i] = [];

      for (var j = 0; j < this.numCols; j++) {
        this[i][j] = opts[i][j];
      }
    }
  } else if (typeof opts === 'object') {  // Passing in dimensions
    this.numRows = opts.rows;
    this.numCols = opts.columns;

    for (var i = 0; i < this.numRows; i++) {
      this[i] = [];

      for (var j = 0; j < this.numCols; j++) {
        if (typeof opts.values === 'function') {
          this[i][j] = opts.values();
        } else if (typeof opts.values === 'number') {
          this[i][j] = opts.values;
        } else {
          this[i][j] = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error('You must supply an object or an array');
  }

  this.dimensions = [this.numRows, this.numCols];
}

/**
 * Add.
 *
 * @param {Matrix} m1
 * @param {Matrix} m2
 * @return {Matrix} result
 */

Matrix.add = function(m1, m2) {
  // Number of rows and columns in first must equal number of rows and columns in second
  if (m1.numRows !== m2.numRows || m1.numCols !== m2.numCols) {
    throw new Error('You can only add matrices with equal dimensions');
  }

  var result = new Matrix({ rows: m1.numRows, columns: m1.numCols });

  for (var i = 0; i < m1.numRows; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < m1.numCols; j++) {
            result[i][j] = m1[i][j] + m2[i][j];
        }
    }

  return result;
};

/**
 * Subtract.
 *
 * @param {Matrix} m1
 * @param {Matrix} m2
 * @return {Matrix} result
 */

Matrix.subtract = function(m1, m2) {
  // Number of rows and number of columns in first must equal number of rows and number of columns in second
  if (m1.numRows !== m2.numRows || m1.numCols !== m2.numCols) {
    throw new Error('You can only subtract matrices with equal dimensions');
  }

  var result = new Matrix({ rows: m1.numRows, columns: m1.numCols });

  for (var i = 0; i < m1.numRows; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < m1.numCols; j++) {
            result[i][j] = m1[i][j] - m2[i][j];
        }
    }

  return result;
};

/**
 * Matrix multiplication.
 *
 * @param {Matrix} m1
 * @param {Matrix} m2
 * @return {Matrix} result
 */

Matrix.multiply = function(m1, m2) {
  var result = Matrix({ rows: m2.numRows, columns: m1.numCols });

  for (var i = 0; i < m2.numRows; i++) {
    result[i] = [];

    for (var j = 0; j < m1.numCols; j++) {
      var sum = 0;

      for (var k = 0; k < m1.numRows; k++) {
        sum += m1[k][j] * m2[i][k];
      }

      result[i][j] = sum;
    }
  }

  return result;
};

/**
 * Scalar multiplication.
 *
 * @param {Matrix} m1
 * @param {Number} num
 * @return {Matrix} result
 */

Matrix.multiplyScalar = function(m1, num) {
  var result = Matrix({ rows: m1.numRows, columns: m1.numCols });

  for (var i = 0; i < m1.numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < m1.numCols; j++) {
      result[i][j] = m1[i][j] * num;
    }
  }

  return result;
};

/**
 * Element-wise multiplcation.
 *
 * @param {Matrix} m1
 * @param {Matrix} m2
 * @return {Matrix} result
 */

Matrix.multiplyElements = function(m1, m2) {
  var result = Matrix({ rows: m1.numRows, columns: m1.numCols })

  for (var i = 0; i < m1.numRows; i++) {
   result[i] = [];

   for (var j = 0; j < m1[i].length; j++) {
     result[i][j] = m1[i][j] * m2[i][j];
   }
  }

  return result;
};

/**
 * Compute the tranpose.
 *
 * @return {Matrix} result
 */

Matrix.prototype.transpose = function() {
  var result = Matrix({ rows: this.numCols, columns: this.numRows });

  for (var i = 0; i < this.numCols; i++) {
    result[i] = [];

    for (var j = 0; j < this.numRows; j++) {
      result[i][j] = this[j][i];
    }
  }

  return result;
};

/**
 * Call a function on each element in the matrix.
 *
 * @param {Function} fn
 * @return {Matrix} result
 */

Matrix.prototype.transform = function(fn) {
  var result = Matrix({ rows: this.numRows, columns: this.numCols });

  for (var i = 0; i < result.numRows; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < result.numCols; j++) {
            result[i][j] = fn(this[i][j]);
        }
    }

  return result;
};

},{}],6:[function(require,module,exports){

/**
 * Expose `sample`.
 */

module.exports = sample;

/**
 * Generate a random sample from the Guassian distribution.
 *
 *  - Uses the Box–Muller transform: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform
 */

function sample() {
  return Math.sqrt(-2 * Math.log(Math.random())) * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * Math.random());
}

},{}],7:[function(require,module,exports){

/**
 * Expose `sigmoidPrime`.
 */

module.exports = sigmoidPrime;

/**
 * Derivative of the sigmoid function.
 *
 * - Used to calculate the deltas in neural networks.
 *
 * @param {Number} z
 */

function sigmoidPrime(z) {
  return Math.exp(-z) / Math.pow(1 + Math.exp(-z), 2);
}

},{}],8:[function(require,module,exports){

/**
 * Expose `sigmoid`.
 */

module.exports = sigmoid;

/**
 * sigmoid.
 *
 *  - Non-linear, continuous, and differentiable logistic function.
 *
 * @param {Number} z
 */

function sigmoid(z) {
  return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-z));
}

},{}]},{},[1])(1)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write your own HTML/JS file, that you can run in the browser, which then uses the mind as a library of functions. The index.js does not run in the browser by itself.

**"Or you can simply use the prebuilt root index.js file directly, which will expose Mind on the window object."**

So you can access it via the window object in your JS file then.

Comment: I already tried calling in a html page but it did not do anything. Can you please tel me what does it mean by opening in window object? I guess they meas the index.js but how can I run it?

Comment: Hey @Akisha, if you are unsure about what the `window` object is, then I would recommend reading a basic JS book such as the Definitive Guide from Flanagan, this will clear up the mystery :-)